# How do I make this JQuery plugin work?

Tags: jquery, html

I found this really cool silky smooth marquee jquery plugin online @:
[Smooth marquee](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/)

I have downloaded the latest JQuery & the JQuery marquee plugin as instructed on the site above. But I still cant get it to work as demonstrated on their site: [The demo](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html).

View my html code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gistfile1.js"></script>

<script> $('marquee').marquee(.pointer) </script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>News Feed</h2>

<div class="pointer" style="display: block-inline; width: 350px; height: 41px; overflow: hidden;">
<div style="float: left; white-space: nowrap; padding: 0px 350px;">

<p>START Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet END</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The feel like the instructions on how to make it work are a bit vague. 
Can someone help me point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    $('.pointer').marquee();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using marquee tag anywhere. Use the tag for achieving sliding effect. The plugin is just making the slidings smoother.
Check below code:
`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="gistfile1.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>News Feed</h2>

    <!-- <div class="pointer" style="display: block-inline; width: 350px; height: 100px; overflow: auto;">
        <div style="float: left; white-space: nowrap; padding: 0px 350px;">

            <marquee>START Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet END</marquee>
        </div>
    </div> -->

    <marquee style="width: 350px;">START Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet END</marquee>

</body>
<script> 
    $('marquee').marquee('')
</script>
</html>
```

`

While going through marquee i also found a fiddle link which might be useful to you: [jsfiddle smooth marquee](http://jsfiddle.net/jithil89/BNBB6/)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(function() {})` as well as putting your class `.pointer` inside `' '`;

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    $('marquee').marquee('.pointer');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('marquee').marquee();
});
```

you need marque in html

```
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="2" width="350">
        <p>START Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet END</p>
    </marquee>
```